# mysql - Unable to start mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have this error when MySQL wants to start:

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
>   (/usr/local/mysql/var/VM_98_215_centos.pid)

And its MySQL error log:

```
170705 12:50:46 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from       /usr/local/mysql/var
170705 12:50:46 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.48-log)   starting as process 9091 ...
170705 12:50:46 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170705 12:50:46 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170705 12:50:46 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170705 12:50:46 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
170705 12:50:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
170705 12:50:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170705 12:50:46 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
170705 12:50:46  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 2437158, file name ./mysql- bin.000030
170705 12:50:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170705 12:50:47 InnoDB: 5.5.48 started; log sequence number 7592792
170705 12:50:47 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
170705 12:50:47 [ERROR] Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'read  error', data_len: 75, event_type: 23
170705 12:50:47 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
170705 12:50:47 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
04:50:47 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this     binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly   built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning     hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=500
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =     406149 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x75f310]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x359)[0x657d79]
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf370)[0x7f32eef57370]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html     contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
170705 12:50:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file     /usr/local/mysql/var/VM_98_215_centos.pid ended
```

Thank you in advance!

## rpm -q centos-release

centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64

Comment: This means you have either a corrupt database or a corrupt file that can't be read `Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'read  error', ` I'd start googling there.

Comment: This would be a better fit for [DBA stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com) They might already [have an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86915/mysqld-got-signal-11-its-my-fault-but-how-do-i-fix-it) there as well

Comment: Agreed. A few quick searches and a common cause for this is being out of disk space. Btw, that link doesn't appear to be the same cause. Definitely the same error message as an end result though.

Comment: Does this mean that my data was lost and can not be recovered?@Alexander

Comment: Not necessarily. Like I said, several results show the error was due to not having disk space. https://dba.stackexchange.com is your best resource for help.